# help with linq to sql insert

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm working with three tables, but only inserting into two( one called images, and the other an intermediate table). They all have relationships.

Tables:

ProductGroups--
ID
Name
ProductGroup_Images--
ProductGroupID
ImagesID
Images-
ImageID
Path

Could the following code be written more elegantly?

```
using (StoreDataContext db = new StoreDataContext())
        {                  
            Image img = new Image
            {
                Path = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mystore/images/public/" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName,    
            };
            db.Images.InsertOnSubmit(img);
            db.SubmitChanges();

            var pg = db.ProductGroups.Where(a => a.Name == txtName.Value).Select(b => b.ID).Single();

            ProductGroups_Image xref = new ProductGroups_Image
            {
                ProductGroupsID = pg,
                ImagesID= img.ImagesID
            };
            db.ProductGroups_Images.InsertOnSubmit(xref);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why worry about IDs, when you have referential properties.

```
Image img = new Image();
img.Path = @"https://s3.amazonaws.com/mystore/images/public/"
  + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;

ProductGroups_Image xref = new ProductGroups_Image();
xref.Image = img;

using (StoreDataContext db = new StoreDataContext())
{
  ProductGroup pg = db.ProductGroups.Where(a => a.Name == txtName.Value).Single();

  xref.ProductGroup = pg;

  db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: awesome, I didn't know you could do it like this. Why do examples in books and online show insert examples that are inside the dataContext using statement and use db.tableName.InsertOnsubmit?

Comment: Books and online examples usually teach the public contract of DataContext and Table<T>, rather than the subtle object-tracking features.

Comment: also what is the @ sign infront of the url string?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following...

```
 ProductGroup temp = db.ProductGroups.Where(a => a.Name == txtName.Value.Select(a).Single();
temp.Images.Add(img);
db.SubmitChanges;
```